# Access to mssql Microsoft SQL server on docker with sqlalchemy flask

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to an mssql server in a docker container using sqlalchemy and flask.

I create the docker container using the following code:

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong_Passw0rd" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -e "MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=True" \
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 \
   -d \
   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-bash).

Then I'm trying to connect to the server using a simple python script with sqlalchemy.

The code for the script is the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sqlalchemy
import urllib
print("Start")
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:localhost:1433;Uid=SA;Pwd=YourStrong_Passw0rd;")
print(f"params: {params}")
connection_str = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" %  params

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_str)
print("Trying connecting")
engine.connect()
print("Connected")

metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=engine)
metadata.reflect(only=['test_table'])

print(metadata.tables)
```

I just want to check if I'm able to connect and then use and access the DB. However, the script gives error at the `engine.connect()` line.

The error that I'm receiving is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

What am I missing?

I tried to change the connection string and try "as" instead of "SA" or the localhost name but was not working.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: What's with the second colon in `Server=tcp:localhost:1433;`? If you're running the Python script directly on the Docker host have you tried `Server=tcp:localhost,1433;` instead? If the Python script is running inside a Docker container (in the same **not-the-default-bridge** network as the SQL Server container) have you tried `Server=tcp:sql1,1433;` instead, or maybe even  `Server=tcp:host.docker.internal,1433;`? Of course port 1433 is the default port, so shouldn't even need to be specified.

Comment: Aside... ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server and later change a default connection property to `Encrypt=yes;` so when connecting to a SQL Server instance that's still using the default self-signed certificate you'll almost always want to either: 1) add the public key of the self-signed certificate to your Trusted Certificates store or 2) add `TrustServerCertificate=yes;` to your connection string. Ref: [ODBC Driver 18 and newer](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connection-string-keywords-and-data-source-names-dsns#odbc-driver-18-and-newer)

Comment: Thanks, @AlwaysLearning. Modifying the connection string with the comma instead of the colons and adding TrustServerCertificate=yes; allowed me to connect to the DB on the docker.
I would like to ask the following question then, what does it change between colons and commas in the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with the connection String and the Certificates of descriptions of the ODBC Drivers 18.

The final connection string used to connect to the docker container running the SQL server, from the host computer running the application was:

```
"Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:localhost,1433;Uid=SA;Pwd=YourStrong_Passw0rd;TrustServerCertificate=yes;"
```